# Stretch div with property css "zoom" in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zooming, stretch

I have a div with the zoom property applied, inside another div.

```
.zoom{
   zoom:0.5;  
}
```

I want that it takes the aspect in google chrome, zoom in the text inside the div and fill all width of the wrapper div.

My problem happens in IE, where the div shrink.

What changes should I do to have the aspect wanted in Internet Explorer?

I made a jsfiddle to test it (http://jsfiddle.net/u0f0fu4f/4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `transform: scale`

This will keep the zoom effect working on IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

The CSS zoom property, it isn't really standard, and it isn't recommended for production apps.

http://jsfiddle.net/u0f0fu4f/5/

```
.zoom{
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(0.5,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: It's not what I really want, but it seems the better and unique solution to the problem. Thank you

Comment: As for the standard bit, see [https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom](canIUse.com). Funny thing is it also says that IE implemented the `zoom` attribute earlier than the other browsers.